# Android Navigation bar position in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, navigationbar, android-navigation-bar

In landscape orientation I need to know if the navigation bar is at the right or left side of the screen so that I can apply paddings to a LinearLayout using WindowInsets to prevent the LinearLayout from overlapping the navigation bar.

Comment: If you're using window insets, it is already telling you where the insets are.

Comment: Might be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057035/detect-android-navigation-bar-orientation this link will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `OrientationEventListener` which returns the orientation of the device in form of `degrees`,the value in `orientation` depends on how the device is tilted,it ranges from 0-360.You might want to `Toast` the values in real-time to know which degree would be reverse landscape and which would be landscape,it's hacky but gets the job done.In portrait it ranges from 0-50,in landscape it ranges from 55-120,in reverse landscape it's >250 but can be as low as 200 if orientation is rapidly changed.An orientation of -1 means that the device is lying flat on a surface.In reverse landscape the `navigation bar` is at the right while in landscape it's at the left.

```
orientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                if(orientation>250){//reverse landscape
                     isReverse=true;
                     }
                else {
                    isReverse=false;
                }
            }
        };

        if (orientationListener.canDetectOrientation()) {

            orientationListener.enable();
        } else {
            orientationListener.disable();
        }
```