# Rotation 180 degrees android doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-camera

If I change left-side-base to right-side-base (both are landscape view modes for user) the application (activity) doesn't recreate. Hense, the camera is shown as horizontaly flipped image. The same result when I try to change position of my device for two portrait modes (normal and inverse). The device detects 90 degree rotation normaly. That is, left-side => portrait => right-size => inverse-portrait => left-side works correctly!

Is it possible to fix this?

I am using Android 4.4.4.

Code:

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0){//0

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90){//1
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180){//2
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270){//3
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "ROTATION:" + display.getRotation() + " ");
```

**EDIT**
I mean, `onResume()` and `SurfaceCreate()` are never call when I rotate the device by 180 degs.

**EDIT CODE OF FUNCTIONS**

```
SurfaceView sfv;
FrameLayout fl0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //some code to initialize
    fl0 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl0);
    sfv = new SurfaceView(this);
    fl0.addView(sfv, 0);
    addSurfaceHolder();
}
private void addSurfaceHolder() {
    SurfaceHolder holder = sfv.getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {


        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, TAG + " surfaceCreated");
            //this function never calls for 180 deg rotation.
            cameraStart(MainActivity.this, false);
            //some code for camera holder connection
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
            Log.d(TAG, TAG + " surfaceChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            ///Some code to destroy camera
            Log.d(TAG, TAG + " surfaceDestroyed");
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + " onResume"); //call for 90 deg rotation. not for 180 deg rotation.
}

public static void cameraStart(Context context, boolean startStopPreview) {

    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = Camera.open(CAMERA_ID); //0
    }

    Camera.Parameters cameraParam = mCamera.getParameters();

    Camera.Size previewSize = cameraParam.getPreviewSize();
    previewFormat = cameraParam.getPreviewFormat();
    frameWidth = previewSize.width;
    frameHeight = previewSize.height;
    frameRect = new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);

    Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) { //0

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90) { //1

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
    } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) { //2

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
    } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) { //3

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "ROTATION:" + display.getRotation() + " "); //just calles for 90 deg rotation. not for 180 deg.
}
```

Comment: Post some code as 'how' you are doing what you just stated.

Comment: have you tried `OrientationEventListener`

Comment: and take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909037/how-to-detect-screen-rotation-through-180-degrees-from-landscape-to-landscape-or) for some hint regarding OrientationEventListener

Comment: Thanks. It works. But rather difficult to implement and catch all states. YOu can write this as answer, I will accept as correct.

Comment: yes this is very annoying the way it is implemented. Could you vote up my answer, would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Change the text in your comment with the correct answer. I will upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the camera's supporting parameters like this:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
```

and add this line before before `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(int);`

```
parameters.setRotation(int);
```

for example:

```
if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0){//0
    parameters.setRotation(90);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90){//1
    parameters.setRotation(0);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
}else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180){//2
    parameters.setRotation(270);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
}else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270){//3
    parameters.setRotation(180);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
}
```

hope this answers your question

**EDIT**

The above code needs to be present also in `onResume()` method because each time orientation is changed `onDestroy()` is called and then `onCreate()` is called so `onResume()` needs to have this piece of code as well as `onCreate()`.

**EDIT 2**

Take a look at [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)

Further more take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909037/how-to-detect-screen-rotation-through-180-degrees-from-landscape-to-landscape-or) question for hint regarding `OrientationEventListener`

Hope you will find this answer a little bit useful.

Comment: Sadly, but no. This doesnt work. Application doesn't recreates.

Comment: have you tried using another device ? which device are you using to test this ?

Comment: and one more question where are you putting this snippet of code ?

Comment: surfaceCreated() method anyway. onResume hasn't called too.

Comment: post your complete relevant code, I'm sure its not a top secret gov project, that way I could assist you better

Comment: Updated the main post